# Problems when trying to enable X11 via SSH

Tags: ubuntu

When placing this command `ssh -X -C -v root@host` does not accept my password on Ubuntu server 22.04. In the `root@host` location I change it to `user@ip`.

But if you put `root@host` it just accepts the password